# Storing salts and password hashes in mongodb

Tags: string, node.js, mongodb, binary, node-mongodb-native

I am using native mongodb-driver for doing inserts and reads from the database. I am creating salts and password hashes using the following methods.

```
var salt;
var passwordHash;

crypto.randomBytes(256, function(ex, buf) {
  if (ex) throw ex;
  console.log('Have %d bytes of random data: %s', buf.length, buf);
  salt = buf;
});

crypto.pbkdf2(user.password, buf, 10000, 128, function(err, hashedPass){
    if (err) throw err;
    passwordHash = hashesPass;
});
```

And now in another function I store this salt and passwordHash into the database like this

```
db.collection('user').insert(
    {
       salt: salt
     , hashedPassword : passwordHash
    }, {w:1}, callback);
```

The salt and hashedPassword are stored as **binary type** in the mongo-db database. **I wanted to know is it good that its stored in binary rather than Strings?** *My concern is due to the statement by node.js that binary data is being depreciated, so not recommended*.

What are the advantges of storing in binary in mongodb if there are any and what are the advantages of storing in strings in mongodb. Which one should I prefer? If strings are better than storing in binary then **How can I make sure that these two things are stored as strings in the database?**

Comment: To make your life easier, why don't you store them as Base64-encoded strings? Binary will be a bit more compact, but we're talking about a few bytes here and the password encryption is comparatively expensive anyway, so why bother?

Comment: what about utf-8 what's the problem in that.

Comment: binary strings are deprecated, not buffers. use buffers.

Comment: How do I store a buffer in Mongodb? It has to be converted to either strings to be stored na? I don't think there is a way to store buffers in mongodb.